# Android - asynctask that fills an adapter for a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter, swiperefreshlayout

Basically the flow is like the following: when a fragment is created (or when the user swipes to refresh the layout), an AsyncTask is executed. The ASyncTask retrieves the info from a URL and setup an adapter which is then assigned to a ListView.

This is the code of the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_page, container, false);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,    
    android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    getTasks();

    return rootView;
}

private void getTasks() {
    new TasksRetriever(mSwipeRefreshLayout,tasksAdapter,lv).execute();
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getTasks();
                }
            }, 1000);
}
```

The TaskRetriever constructor is:

```
public TasksRetriever(SwipeRefreshLayout srl, TasksAdapter ta, ListView lv) {
    adpt = ta;
    this.srl = srl;
    this.lv = lv;
}
```

and postExecute is:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<TasksItem> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (adpt == null) adpt = new TasksAdapter(result);
    else adpt.setItemList(result);
    lv.setAdapter(adpt);
    adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    srl.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Not sure yet if it works but I was wondering if I'm on the right track because it doesn't look clean to me. On the other hand, I can't create the adapter and assign it to the ListView until I actually have data for it... Is this considering OK or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: you CAN create an empty adapter and fill it later - in AsyncTask

Comment: You are on the right track. If you are always loading a new list (instead of adding itens) to the adapter, you can create a new adapter and set it to the list view(by the way you can get the adapter by listView.getAdapter() ). I also suggest you to add a progressDialog in your TasksRetriever, because if the user touchs or operate the device while the list is loading it can cause a freeze on the ui or unwanted behavior.

Comment: the adapter is public class TasksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TasksItem> so I did super(Utils.context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList); itemList contains the list - can I pass null? or maybe I don't need to Super?

Comment: So passing all 3 objects (layout, adapter, listview) to the asynctask, is the correct way and I just need to re-organize the code as suggested here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the list adapter up in the onCreate() method under your list view and make this a instance variable (not a local one) so that the Async task can access it as follows i.e.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mAdpt = new TasksAdapter(null);
    lv.setAdapter(mAdpt);

}
```

And then in your onPostExecute()

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<TasksItem> result) {
    dialog.dismiss();  
    mAdpt.clear();
    for( TaskItem ti : result ) 
    {
      mAdpt.add( ti );
    }
    mAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    srl.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Also make sure you account for the null value being passed into your adapter in the getView() method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note, `mAdpt.clear` should be `mAdpt.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

you CAN create an empty adapter and fill it later - in AsyncTask

your `onPostExecute()` should look like:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<TasksItem> result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (adpt == null){
      adpt = new TasksAdapter(result);
      lv.setAdapter(adpt);
    }else{
      adpt.clear();
    }
    for( TaskItem ti : result ) adpt.add( ti );
    adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    srl.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: in the adapter I have public void setItemList(List<TasksItem> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    } - I guess using adpt.clear; and adpt.add() is better coding or there isn't much difference?

Comment: @Amos there is a clear difference in resource allocation. You should only create the `adapter` once, and modify the underlying data-set as needed. Creating a new `Adapter` is heavy work. Hence why I upvoted Andy B's answer.

Comment: you can do whatever you want with the backing list :) the problem is, that the changes are not reflected in the `listview` until you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The only place to call it is the `onPostExcecute()`

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know I'm writing good/clean code and not just a working one (which is easy :))